# When using type=module why the relative paths require .js extension but aliased paths do not?

Tags: typescript

Using `{"type": "module"}` in `package.json` and `{"module": "es2020",}` in `tsconfig.json`.

```
import { expandedTransformKuleditorToContraSlate } from '../components/expandedTransformKuleditorToContraSlate.js';
```

complains about the missing extension (as it should), but...

```
import { expandedTransformKuleditorToContraSlate } from '@/components/expandedTransformKuleditorToContraSlate';
```

does not complain.

Alias is configured with:

```
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
```

I would like to have them both complain.